# incrementing and printing the number of characters in a array without using strlen()

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that displays the number of characters in an array, the program has to use a function so I made a while loop in the function to count the characters +1 escape charcter after. However I have no idea why this isn't working as im very new to  C and woud appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>         
#include <stdlib.h>          

char stringLength (char *count)       
{                       
    count = 0;                          
    while(count[0] != '\0')                        
    {                          
        ++count;                    
    };                              
    ++count;                                   

    return *count;                                        
}                                   

int main()                                      
{                                       
    char count[50] = {"hello how many characters are here :)"};
    int v = stringLength(count);                          
    printf("%c", count[v]);                                
}
```

Comment: The first thing your function does is set `count` to 0.  It now points to nothing.  Remove that assignment.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the sanity of `printf("%c", count[v])`  once you get back your result. If `v` is accurate, it will always refer to the terminating nullchar, and one past that (therefore undefined behavior) if you're trying to include the nullchar location as part of your length result).

Comment: Also I know this can be done simpler with the sizeof operator but im trying to do it a diffrent way :)

Comment: There's many problems with the function and the way you use it. Besides the null-pointer dereference you have (mentioned in a previous comment) you return the null-terminator, which will be zero.

Comment: You while loop is always checking the first entry in the array of count to be null - this is your problem and that you are setting it to null as @WilliamPursell said

Comment: As for one common way to solve your problem, keep the pointer to the string as a *separate* variable, and the `count` being an actual counter of characters.

Comment: Also note that `strlen` does *not* count the terminator, if you want to make your function compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the array pointer parameter (`char* count`) both for storing the string and the number of characters. Just use a separate counter variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>         
//#include <stdlib.h> - you are not using this header, why include it?          

int stringLength(const char* s) //return type is int      
{                       
    int count = 0;                          
    while (s[0] != '\0')                        
    {                          
        ++count;
        ++s;
        //this could have been done much easier with a for-loop, but I will stick with the way you did it
    }                              
    ++count;                                   

    return count;                                        
}                                   

int main()                                      
{                                       
    char count[50] = "hello how many characters are here :)"; //don't use {} for string initialization
    int v = stringLength(count);                          
    printf("%d", v); //you were printing count[v] which is not inside the string                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//count every character in a string
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char str[100],str2[50],i,j,count,exist=0,k;
    printf("Enter your String=");
    gets(str);

int length = strlen(str);

for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    //exist is used to check if the character is already counted , 0 for no and 1 for yes
    exist = 0;
    for(j=0;j<length;j++)
    {
        
        if(str[i]==str2[j])
        {
            exist = 1;
        }
    }
    //will start iff character is not counted
    if(exist==0)
    {
        str2[i] = str[i];
        count = 1;
        for(k=i+1;k<length;k++)
        {
            if(str[k]==str[i])
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        // blank space is not included
        //remove if statement to print number of blank spaces too
        if(str[i]!=' ')
        {
            printf("\n%c = %d",str[i],count);
        }
        
    }
}
```

}